# Delete all files except files with no extension in command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard, delete-file

I have an application that dumps logs to a folder. It writes the files the most recent file without an extension and each old version gets a .1, .2, .3, etc. appended to the end.

Example:

```
Filename   
Filename.1  
Filename.2  
Filename.3
```

I would like to write a basic script that erases "`filename.?`", but whenever i write something like

```
del /s "Filename.?"
```

or

```
del /s "filename.*"
```

It erases everything with that filename.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Windows, put this in a file named something like "exclude_delete.bat":

```
@echo off & setlocal

if "%1"=="" goto :syntax

set wildcard=%1

for %%f in (%wildcard%) do (
  if not "%%~xf"=="" (
    echo Deleting: %%f
    del "%%f"
  ) else (
    echo Keeping: %%f
  )
)

goto :eof

:syntax
echo. Syntax: %0 ^<wildcard^>
echo.
echo. Example: to delete every file "Filename.*" except "Filename":
echo.   %0 Filename.*
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way, if you don't mind temporarily renaming the file:

```
ren filename filename_keep
del filename.*
ren filename_keep filename
```

Comment: This was my first thought and it would work perfectly if i could rename that file. Thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a little python script for fun.

```
import os

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        if '.' in f:
            os.remove(f)
```

Just pop open a python shell and run this, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for this I never used python before, I am getting a book on it and will start playing around. Thanks for this quick response!